# Ruby/Rails: How to sort icalendar file data by dtstart?

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I am using the [icalendar](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) gem to parse arbitrary public Google Calendar ICS exports and display them in a Rails applications. The problem is that the events are showing up in reverse alphabetical order. I am trying to figure out how to sort them in chronological order by start time (dtstart).

Controller:

```
require 'icalendar'
require 'net/https'

uri = URI('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/7d9i7je5o16ec6cje702gvlih0hqa9um%40import.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics')
# above is an example calendar of Argentinian holidays
# the actual calendar would theoretically have hour/minute start/end times
calendar = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
cals = Icalendar::Calendar.parse(calendar)
cal = cals.first
@holidays = cal.events
```

View:

```
<% @holidays.each do |x| %>
        <div class="event">
            <div class="event-title"><strong><%= x.summary.upcase %></strong></div>
            <div class="event-room">Room <%= x.location %><span class="event-time"><%= x.dtstart.strftime('%I:%M%p') + ' to ' + x.dtend.strftime('%I:%M%p') %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

This results in the events rendering in the DOM in reverse alphabetical order rather than chronological order (preferably by dtstart).

Unfortunately, it seems the `sort_by!` method within `ICalendar` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. Redo the controller like so:

```
require 'icalendar'
require 'net/http'

    uri = URI('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/7d9i7je5o16ec6cje702gvlih0hqa9um%40import.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics')
    calendar = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    cals = Icalendar::Calendar.parse(calendar)
    cal = cals.first
    all_events = cal.events
    @sorted_events = all_events.sort! { |a,b| a.dtstart <=> b.dtstart }
```

Then use @sorted_events instead of @holidays in your view:

```
<% @sorted_events.each do |x| %>
        <div class="event">
            <div class="event-title"><strong><%= x.summary.upcase %></strong></div>
            <div class="event-room">Room <%= x.location %><span class="event-time"><%= x.dtstart.strftime('%I:%M%p') + ' to ' + x.dtend.strftime('%I:%M%p') %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

That should do the trick. The `.sort!` method doesn't work in `irb`.